# Phase Diagram-Fe-C, and TTT: Hardness Scale

Tags: phase, alloy

So far I know that the Hardess scale of these materials is this:

Martensite> Bainite> Perlite > Cementite> Ferrite

Where is Austenite along this scale? I know that Cementite is harder than Austenite.

Comment: Google, Wikipedia, and your closest copy of a metals handbook would be good starting points...

Comment: This is much too general statement to have an answer. "Hard "martensite is softer then cementite . Depending on the heat-treat condition one could rewrite the listing several ways.